# JQuery -How to fadeOut instead of Sliding up?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have 2 sections called .about-us and .price-list. With 2 buttons that activates them .prices and .about-us-btn. The 2 sections both are hidden by default with JQuery and have a .slideToggle event for each, if one is visible though, it'll slide up if I click the other button for it.

Now I figured, instead of sliding back up, they can do a fadeOut event. It works, but only if   the .price-list is visible first, then click on .prices. (both sections are in the same position, but only one are visible when I click a button). If .about-us is visible first, then if I click on the .prices button, the .about-us will slideUp instead of fading out.

Will anyways. Hope you understand and can help me out!. Heres my JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  // Price-list & About-us are hidden by Javascript
  $("aside.price-list, aside.about-us").hide();
  // Create a slide for the price-list
    $("button.prices").click(function(){
      $("aside.about-us").fadeOut(300);
      $("aside.price-list").slideToggle(300);
  }); 
  // Create a slide for the about-us
    $("button.about-btn").click(function(e){
        $("aside.about-us").slideToggle(300);
        $("aside.price-list").fadeOut(300);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) you should use [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) explicitly here (since you don't know what state they're in initially, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("aside.price-list, aside.about-us").hide();
  $("button.prices").click(function() {
    $("aside.about-us").fadeOut(300);
    $("aside.price-list").slideDown(300);
  }); 
  $("button.about-btn").click(function() {
    $("aside.about-us").slideDown(300);
    $("aside.price-list").fadeOut(300);
  });
});
```

Or, if you wanted to completely fade each out before the slide happened on the other, use the [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) callback, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("aside.price-list, aside.about-us").hide();
  $("button.prices").click(function() {
    $("aside.about-us").fadeOut(300, function() {
      $("aside.price-list").slideDown(300);
    });
  }); 
  $("button.about-btn").click(function() {
    $("aside.price-list").fadeOut(300, function() {
      $("aside.about-us").slideDown(300);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create jQuery Accordian effect. The following link should help you.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion